# How can we get a string value from js file to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

How can we pass a string from js file to HTML? Assume I have declared a string in privacy.js and I need to get in to my html text area.

I have imputed the script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/privacy.js"></script>
```

I am assinging string value in to a div

```
document.getElementById("privacy_text").innerHTML = privacy_string;
```

I need the Sting value in text area

```
<textarea class="terms" readonly="readonly">
                 <div id="privacy_text"></div>
             </textarea>
```

Comment: You can't have a div inside textarea!

Comment: So how can I get the value in to text area?

Comment: Assign ID to textarea and try  `document.getElementById("privacy_text").innerHTML = "TEXT";` [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/34E43/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't embed a div in a textarea and rather assign it it's own id:

```
<textarea id="privacy_textarea"></textarea>
```

And then try to assign a value to it:

```
document.getElementById("privacy_textarea").value = privacy_string;
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/J9CSK/) is a working example.

You could as well use innerHTML but textarea is a form element so I'd recommend to use value.

Answer (score 2):

Give your textarea an ID like, this

```
<textarea class="terms" readonly="readonly" id="theTextarea">
</textarea>
```

and then use the following JavaScript to select it and change the value:

```
document.getElementById("theTextarea").value = "theValue";
```

If you have access to jQuery, you can use:

```
$("#theTextarea").val("theValue");
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zcn8t/1/)

Either way, a `div` can't go inside a `textarea`.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function printValue()
{
var name="Anand";
document.getElementById("textbox1").innerHTML=name;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="textbox1"/>
<input type="button" value="GetText" onclick="PrintValue()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can assign an ID to your textarea...

```
<textarea id="myTextArea"></textarea>
```

Then this should work:

```
document.getElementById("myTextArea").value = privacy_string;
```

Comment: (or, use another way to get ahold of the textarea via javascript syntax - in any event, use the value property)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.innerHtml`, use this:

```
document.getElementById("privacy_text").value= "Hello";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Give that textarea an ID , then set value to text area like document.getElementById('your text area id').value=privacy_text; from javascript file.
eg:
<script>
var privacy_text="your string";
document.getElementById(textId).value=privacy_text;
</script>
<textarea id="textId"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.querySelector(".terms").value = 'someValue';
```

You can find HTML elements from javascript using [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) by using different type of "query filters" in the above example it is finding the text area by CSS class using `.cssClass`.

Regarding the div inside your textarea object please note that is not possible. You can only non-HTML text.